# Javascript array undefined and how to display in calendar

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm writing an array but cannot the values. memberData[0] always gets undefined. How to get correct values (1,2)?

After getting the correct values, these need to use for loop to display in calendar. I don't know how to display in a for loop way like the picture. Please help!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmLm0.png)

My code below:

```
         var memberList = {"member":
            {
                "1":"1,2",
                "2":"1,2",
                "3":"1,2",
                "4":"1,2",
                "5":"1,2",
                "6":"1,2",
                "7":"1,2",
                "8":"1,2",
                "9":"1,2",
                "10":"1,2",
                "11":"1,2",
                "12":"1,2",
                "13":"1,2",
                "14":"1,2",
                "15":"1,2",
                "16":"1,2",
                "17":"1,2",
                "18":"1,2",
                "19":"1,2",
                "20":"1,2",
                "21":"1,2",
                "22":"1,2",
                "23":"1,2",
                "24":"1,2",
                "25":"1,2",
                "26":"1,2",
                "27":"1,2",
                "28":"1,2",
                "29":"1,2",
                "30":"1,2"
            }
        };
        var memberData = memberList["member"];
        var res = memberData[0].split(",");
        var am = 'AM' + '-' + res[0];   
        var pm = 'PM' + '-' + res[1];
```

Comment: The main problem is that it's not an array. It's an object. Anyway, even if it were an array, you haven't defined item 0 so why is it surprising that `memberData[0]` is undefined?

Comment: It's absolutely not clear what you want.

Comment: Juhana: Oh...thanks to correct me. It's an object, got it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a for loop which you wanted

```
  for(i=0;i<Object.keys(memberList.member).length;i++)
    {

        var num = Object.keys(memberList.member)[i];

        var memberData = memberList["member"][num];

        //alert(memberData);
        var res = memberData.split(",");

        alert("AM "+res[0]+" & PM "+res[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`member` of `memberList` is not an array, it's an object. You need to change `member` to be an array.

```
var memberList = {member: [1, 2, 3, ...]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are accessing object key with an array index. To access object value you need to use the corresponding key

Demo code to implement your use case is as follows:-

```
var memberData = memberList["member"];
var keys = Object.keys(memberData);

for ( var key in keys ) {
    var res = memberData[key].split(",");
    var am = 'AM' + '-' + res[0];   
    var pm = 'PM' + '-' + res[1];
}
```

This code will access each value inside object memberData.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, you have an object with keys, based on one whereas arrays are based on zero. For the access without changing the structure just add one to the key and do the access you want.

**But** I suggest to use a different data structure like arrays or try to indicate right, starting with one.

```js
var memberList = { "member": { "1": "1,2", "2": "1,2", "3": "1,2", "4": "1,2", "5": "1,2", "6": "1,2", "7": "1,2", "8": "1,2", "9": "1,2", "10": "1,2", "11": "1,2", "12": "1,2", "13": "1,2", "14": "1,2", "15": "1,2", "16": "1,2", "17": "1,2", "18": "1,2", "19": "1,2", "20": "1,2", "21": "1,2", "22": "1,2", "23": "1,2", "24": "1,2", "25": "1,2", "26": "1,2", "27": "1,2", "28": "1,2", "29": "1,2", "30": "1,2" } },
    memberData = memberList["member"],
    res = memberData[0 + 1].split(","),
    //                 ^^^                    add one for the index starting with one
    am = 'AM' + '-' + res[0],
    pm = 'PM' + '-' + res[1];

console.log(am + ' ' + pm);
```